# Convert string to a UI element name - Win 8

Tags: c#, string, windows-8.1, uielement

The heading may not clearly explain what I'm trying to achieve. This is what I need. I have an array of strings. There is a UI element with that name. Eg arr[0] has Ach. There is a checkbox with name Ach.

How do I use the string Ach and refer it to the checkbox named Ach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use [FrameworkElement.FindName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method passing control name as method parameter, for example :

```
var ach = (CheckBox)this.FindName(arr[0]);
```